# Running Meteor app with Nginx SSL proxy on Kubernetes

Tags: ssl, meteor, nginx, proxy, kubernetes

I have a Meteor app deployed using Kubernetes on Google Cloud, configured with Nginx acting as SSL termination. Everything working ok.

However, it appears that if two different clients connect to two different SSL containers, updates don't show up on the respective apps for up to 10 seconds, which makes it seem that Websockets isn't working, but polling is taking effect. I have confirmed that all clients are connected with Websockets, but since updates do not propagate immediately, perhaps Nginx isn't configured to correctly talk with the Meteor app.

Here's my SSL/Nginx service:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend-ssl
  labels:
    name: frontend-ssl
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  - name: https
    port: 443 
    targetPort: 443 
  selector:
    name: frontend-ssl
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 123.456.123.456
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP`

And here is the Meteor service:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend
  labels:
    name: frontend
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    name: flow-frontend
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 123.456.123.456
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP`

For SSL termination, I'm using the Kubernetes suggested SSL setup forked with Websockets additions https://github.com/markoshust/nginx-ssl-proxy

Comment: You're pointing 123.456.123.456 at both Services (or is that a typo)? I'm not familiar with meteor, but there's a chance your problem is not a meteor problem. You should have at least 2 pods (preferably managed by 2 RCs), and 2 Services, one for nginx and one for your app. Only the nginx Service needs to be Type=Loadbalacer.

Comment: To narrow down the unknowns, you can force the pods to land on the same node using node selectors (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/docs/user-guide/node-selection/README.md#step-one-attach-label-to-the-node). You can also point an nginx instance directly at the service with something like `proxy_pass http://svcName.svcNamespace.svc.cluster.local:svcPort` in your config (assuming you have cluster DNS working and can resolve your service name with eg nslookup). Let me know how this goes.

Comment: Nginx and Meteor both have separate rcs and pods. I figured only nginx needs Type=LoadBalancer, however I don't think having that in the meteor side should affect anything. They do live on the same IP, however that just makes both publicly available, each on their own port.

Comment: In response to your second comment, I don't want pods landing on the same instances, because that sort of defeats the purpose of running kubernetes. I want to potentially run my meteor app on 100 pods located across 100 different instances. I'm in fact using `proxy_pass http://target_service:port` to route requests from nginx to meteor.

Comment: FYI, I did remove type=LoadBalancer from my meteor service. Things run the same, however.

Comment: I obviously wasn't recommending running pods on a single node for all production cases, just to debug. Can you tcpdump traffic leaving the container bridge (cbr0, docker0) of nginx to figure where it's getting dropped (something like `tcpdump -i docker0 -n host svc-ip`)?

Comment: Where do I run this command? What do docker0, host and svc-ip each refer to?

Answer (score 0):

In your NginX config, did you make sure to use the `ip_hash` flag to direct websockets to the same server each time? also you need to make sure the websocket Upgrade headers are forwarded:

```
upstream meteorapp{
     ip_hash;
     server   hostname:port
}
server {
    # your server stuff here
    # 
    location / {
        proxy_pass                  http://meteorapp;
        proxy_set_header            Host $host;
        proxy_set_header            X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_http_version          1.1;
        proxy_set_header            Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header            Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-Proto http;
        proxy_redirect              http:// $scheme://;
    }
}
```

Comment: Arg no... a one-liner, pfft. Let me test this. Thanks mucho!

Comment: No-go. Adding the `ip_hash` line seemed to have no effect.

Comment: what about the upgrade headers?

Comment: It appears I already have those set. Here is my nginx config. https://github.com/markoshust/nginx-ssl-proxy/tree/master/nginx

Comment: sorry not sure. I would try commenting things like: ssl_session_tickets off;
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
  resolver_timeout 5s; which are making calls outside and may be slowing things down?

Comment: It's not really an issue with speed. Sometimes, everything is immediate. Every other time, it's exactly 10 seconds. Some kind of polling is going on.

Comment: well, 10s might match the 5s try to the 2 dns servers. did you check if your nginx instance could reach those?

Comment: Hmm I never thought of that. I'll check this out.

Comment: No-go. If `resolver_timeout` times out, it will lead nginx to throw a 500 error, so that isn't the issue.

Comment: Hmmmm. I wonder if this is it, looks like GCE doesn't offer session affinity, you need to be whitelisted first to even test it out. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#session_affinity

Comment: this is confusing because i have a few meteor site being nginx on kubernetes and don't have this issue

Comment: Can you post your dockerfiles & nginx configs?

Comment: FYI, I've confirmed meteor's oplog listener is setup properly, and there are no probs with DNS/nginx/etc. This problem seems to be related to kubernetes.

Comment: Are you still having this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to run your app would be using Nginx based ingress controller instead of Nginx service.

In my opinion the easiest way to deploy ingress controller is with helm:
https://docs.helm.sh/using_helm/#installing-helm
https://kubeapps.com/charts/stable/nginx-ingress

But if you prefer not adding another tool to your stack you can use official installation guide: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/deploy.

Example ingress object configuration with web sockets support can be found here: https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/websocket

Comment: This is probably correct. I moved off of Kubernetes for a few reasons, but there had to be something going on with Nginx here.